# How many SMS and contacts can be stored in an iPhone

Tags: iphone

I want to know how many (number of ) SMS and Contact details can be stored in an iPhone 3gs and iPhone 4.

Comment: Not an exact answer: I kept almost 2,000 messages on my old 3G. Thought the info might be useful for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I remember there used to be a limit in early iPhones on early software, something around 2000? But I don't think there is a limit these days.

Text messages are stored in SQLite database which has very, very large limits of number of rows. I managed to store over 3000 messages on my iPhone 3G.

Comment: so there is no way that the messages would have been deleted by the iPhone?

Comment: I am not aware of any reason why iPhone on its own would do such thing.